# Como exibir mensagem de erro e redirecionar em jQuery

Tags: php, ajax

Tô tentando exibir a mensagem de dados incorretos via Ajax mais não tô conseguindo, o que estou fazendo de errado? E o header não está redirecionando

**Ajax**

```
$(".form_log").submit(function(){   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(".form_log").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $(".resp").html(data);
        },
        error: function(request, status, error){
            $(".resp").html(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

**PHP**

```
session_start();
include_once("pdo/config.php");
$conn = conexao();
if(empty($_POST['user'])){
    echo '<span class="msg error">preencha seu login</span>';
}elseif(empty($_POST['pass'])){
    echo '<span class="msg error">preencha sua senha</span>';
}else{

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $log = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE user = '$user' AND pass = '$pass'");
    $log->execute();
    $count_log = $log->rowCount();
    if($count_log >=1){
        $row_log = $log->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        foreach($row_log AS $list_log){
            $_SESSION['nome'] = $list_log->nome;
            $_SESSION['sobrenome'] = $list_log->sobrenome;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $list_log->email;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $list_log->user;
            $_SESSION['captcha'] = $list_log->captcha;
            header("refresh: 3; bem-vindo.php");
            echo '<span class="msg success">aguarde...</span>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<span class="msg error">dados incorretos</span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O Ajax retorna dados. O *header* é uma função PHP que só vai ser processado no servidor, ou seja, ele não faz nenhum efeito no Ajax.

Você deve fazer o redirecionamento pelo próprio JavaScript quando o Ajax retornar a mensagem de sucesso. Uma sugestão é verificar se no retorno possui a string "success" referente à classe `success` da span retornada:

```
if(~data.indexOf("success")){

   setTimeout(function(){

      location.href = "bem-vindo.php";

   }, 3000);

}
```

O `setTimeout` com o valor `3000` significa que o redirecionamento se dará após 3 segundos (3000 milissegundos). Seu código ficaria assim:

**JS:**

```
$(".form_log").submit(function(){   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(".form_log").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $(".resp").html(data);

            if(~data.indexOf("success")){

               setTimeout(function(){

                  location.href = "bem-vindo.php";

               }, 3000);

            }
        },
        error: function(request, status, error){
            $(".resp").html(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**PHP:**

Além do *header* não funcionar com Ajax, ele ainda está no lugar errado, dentro de um laço `foreach`. Isso provavelmente está causando um erro no PHP.

Basta remover a linha `header("refresh: 3; bem-vindo.php");` e colocar o `echo '<span class="msg success">aguarde...</span>';` após o `foreach`:

```
foreach($row_log AS $list_log){
   $_SESSION['nome'] = $list_log->nome;
   $_SESSION['sobrenome'] = $list_log->sobrenome;
   $_SESSION['email'] = $list_log->email;
   $_SESSION['user'] = $list_log->user;
   $_SESSION['captcha'] = $list_log->captcha;
}
echo '<span class="msg success">aguarde...</span>';
```

Comment: só por curiosidade minha mesmo, por que usou o setTimeout para fazer o redirecionamento apenas 3s dps?

Comment: Oi @Will. Foi por causa do `refresh: 3;` que ele estava usando no `header`.